# How to delete a file in Pantheon File Manager?

Tags: pantheon-files

My laptop doesn't have <kbd>DEL</kbd> key, so I mapped <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>BackSpace</kbd> to behave as <kbd>DEL</kbd> key. It works correctly in Scratch text editor or even in Google Chrome when I delete a text, but doesn't respond in Pantheon File Manager when I try to delete a file/folder.

Comment: I have a DEL key and that works for removing files.  
Right click > "Move to Trash" works?  
Maybe have a look around in their issue queue: https://github.com/elementary/files

Comment: @PeterUithoven Yes right click works okay.